# position a svg at the bottom of full screen image div

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to position an svg separator at bottom part of an image `div`.
Here is css for the latter:

```
.second-content {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #999;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://us-east.manta.joyent.com/condenast/public/cnt-services/production/2015/08/25/55dc9569f073f4db64845993_eiffel-tower-paris.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Here is the relevant html part:

```
<div class="second-content">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 0 L70 100 L100 0 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M70 100 L100 40 L100 0 Z" />
    </svg>
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" style="bottom:0" height="100"  viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 100 L30 0 L100 100 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M30 0 L100 40 L100 100 Z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

I've tried some ways to fix the content at the bottom of the div but none of them worked for me.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `.second-content` as relative
And then add `{position: absolute}` to the other two elements.
Then to the first one add `{top: 0}` and to the other `{bottom: 0}`

```css
body,html,.second-content {height: 100%; margin: 0}
.second-content {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   position: relative
}
.second-content svg:first-child,
.second-content svg:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.second-content svg:last-child {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="second-content" style="background-color: #369">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 0 L70 100 L100 0 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M70 100 L100 40 L100 0 Z" />
    </svg>
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" style="bottom:0" height="100"  viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 100 L30 0 L100 100 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M30 0 L100 40 L100 100 Z" />
    </svg>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="second-content" style="background-color: #396">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 0 L70 100 L100 0 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M70 100 L100 40 L100 0 Z" />
    </svg>
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" style="bottom:0" height="100"  viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path stroke="white" fill="white" d="M0 100 L30 0 L100 100 Z" />
        <path stroke="#f4f4f4" fill="#f4f4f4" d="M30 0 L100 40 L100 100 Z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You can even set as -1px instead of zero to remove the "gray line"